# How to display Place Autocomplete Result on Google Map

Tags: java, android, dictionary, kotlin

I have Implemented google map and Display the my current location on Map.

Now I have implemented Place Autocomplete and this  getting Result  getting successfully

```
 override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place) {
    Log.i("TAG", "Place Selected: " + place.name)
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(place.attributions)) {
        Log.d("TAG", place.attributions.toString())
    }
 }
```

Now I want to display this place Name to my google Map. How we can achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to add a marker on the point of that place and show the name of that place on the title of marker.
Something like:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
.title("Your position")).showInfoWindow();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use the below code to implement autocomplete

```
 var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }
```

Comment: That sounds like Javascript, not Kotlin/Java